# Strange results with .parent() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basicly I wanna add a class called "active" both to the li you click on and the "category div". In this case the div with the id "vadarmindfulness". I thought my code would work but it does not.

The jQuery code:

```
    $('.downdrop li').click(function() {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.info-title').hide().load('content.html' + " #" + currentId + "-title").fadeIn(400);
    $('.info-text').hide().load('content.html' + " #" + currentId + "-text").fadeIn(400);

    $(this).addClass('active');
    alert($(this).parent().parent().next().addClass('active'));
});
```

The HTML code:

```
<ul id="dropdown">
                    <li class="twolines"><div id="vadarmindfulness" class="active">Vad är mindfulness</div>
                        <ul class="downdrop">
                            <li id="hurserprogrammetut"><a href="#">Hur ser programmet ut</a></li>
                            <li id="effekterochbiverkningar">Effekter och ev. biverkningar</li>
                            <li id="evidens">Evidens</li>
                            <li id="sammanfattning">Sammanfattning av forskning</li>
                            <li id="egenforskning">Vår egen forskning</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Please refrain from using curse words in your posts if you want to be taken seriously by the community.

Comment: I LOL'd at your title and took you seriously regardless of your use of the English language.

Comment: I don't see any "category div" here, could you add your full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets get a look at what this does

```
$(this).parent().parent().next().addClass('active')
```

HTML

```
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li class="twolines"> <!-- 2nd parent -->
        <div id="vadarmindfulness">Vad är mindfulness</div>
        <ul class="downdrop"> <!-- first parent -->
            <li id="hurserprogrammetut"><a href="#">Hur ser programmet ut</a></li>
            <li id="effekterochbiverkningar">Effekter och ev. biverkningar</li>
            <li id="evidens">Evidens</li>
            <li id="sammanfattning">Sammanfattning av forskning</li>
            <li id="egenforskning">Vår egen forskning</li> <!-- clicked -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- next() goes here / there is no next becuase it gets the next element after 2nd parent (not the element inside the 2nd parent!) -->
</ul>
```

What you want is

```
$(this).parent().prev().addClass('active');
```

HTML

```
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li class="twolines">
        <div id="vadarmindfulness">Vad är mindfulness</div> <!-- previous element of 1st parent -->
        <ul class="downdrop"> <!-- first parent -->
            <li id="hurserprogrammetut"><a href="#">Hur ser programmet ut</a></li>
            <li id="effekterochbiverkningar">Effekter och ev. biverkningar</li>
            <li id="evidens">Evidens</li>
            <li id="sammanfattning">Sammanfattning av forskning</li>
            <li id="egenforskning">Vår egen forskning</li> <!-- clicked -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.closest('selector')` instead of `.parent().parent()`.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

EDIT: Also, it seems like you're using `.next()` wrong. It selects the first element after the element you call it on, not its first child. You can use `$('div', someParentElement)` to get any child, or `.children().first()` to get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Heres' a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pW9qC/4/) that explicitly sets the `active` class to the div in question. If that's not what you wanted, then simply use `$(this).parent().prev().addClass('active')` instead of `next()`.